# Is just one W-type enough for formalizing mathematics?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, constructive-mathematics

We work in intensional Martin-Löf type theory with $0$, $1$, $2$, $\Pi$, $\Sigma$, $W$ and a cumulative hierarchy of universes. Suppose our goal is to formalize constructive mathematics.

Now if we were to drop general $W$-types but keep just one $W$-type with infinitely many closed terms how much more difficult would our life become? Would it be much harder to express interesting theorems?

Answer (score 3):

We certainly do not need very many $W$-types.

If we also have universes, we only need one $W$-type, namely the natural numbers. For example, the [UniMath](https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath) library uses just the natural numbers and no other inductive types (if we discount the fact that standard types constructors, such as products and sum, are defined inductively in Coq).